# D3.js Issue with .csv - Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M499.99730980162605,187.54702784048158L499.99731009247085,

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, csv, d3.js

I'm working on a d3.js based chart and I'm receiving an,

"Error: Invalid value for  attribute: d="M499.99730980162605,187.54702784048158L499.99731009247085,...".

I'm trying to chart cycling data in a .csv format that looks like,

```
record,5,timestamp,positionlat,positionlong,distance,altitude,speed,temperature
data,5,2015-05-25 18:33:19,467885825,"-1,275,710,534",8.25,"2,402.6",7.976,20
data,5,2015-05-25 18:33:24,467886510,"-1,275,704,356",53.3,"2,402.6",9.552,19
data,5,2015-05-25 18:33:25,467886903,"-1,275,703,091",63.16,"2,402.6",9.581,19
data,5,2015-05-25 18:33:27,467887866,"-1,275,700,622",83.15,"2,402.6",9.69,19
data,5,2015-05-25 18:33:30,467889786,"-1,275,696,923",115.37,"2,394.2",10.064,19
data,5,2015-05-25 18:33:32,467891098,"-1,275,694,820",134.88,"2,394.2",9.715,19
data,5,2015-05-25 18:33:34,467892345,"-1,275,692,669",154.28,"2,394.2",9.588,19
data,5,2015-05-25 18:33:36,467893324,"-1,275,690,252",174,"2,394.2",9.825,19
```

Here is the code

```
d3.csv(activityFile.url(), function(d){

    return {
        timestamp : new Date(d.timestamp),
        speed : +d.speed,
        altitude : +d.altitude.replace(/\,/g,''),
        distance : +d.distance.replace(/\,/g,''),
        //timeDone : parseDate(d.timestamp)
    };

    function sortByDateAscending(a, b) {
        // Dates will be cast to numbers automagically:
        return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
    }

    data = data.sort(sortByDateAscending);

},function(data) {

    maxTime = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp;} );
    maxAlt = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.altitude;} );
    maxSpeed = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.speed;} );

    //timeDone = parseDate(d.timestamp);

    console.log(maxAlt);
    console.log(maxTime);
    console.log(maxSpeed);

    var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("id", "theChart")
        .attr("width", chartRowWidth)
        .attr("height", chartRowWidth/aspect);

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                     .domain([0, maxTime])
                     .range([0, chartRowWidth]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                     .domain([0, maxSpeed])
                     .range([0, chartRowWidth/aspect]);

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d)  {  return xScale(d.timestamp); })
        .y(function(d) {  return yScale(d.speed); });


    chart.append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area(data));  //around here

});
```

I thank I'm receiving the error on the thirst to last line.  I really don't understand why I'm having this issue.

Sidenote, for some reason the maxAlt value actually has been returning the maximum positionlat value. Don't know why this is happening either.

Thanks

Comment: Your scales might be wrong. The bottom end of the domains is 0. You probably want the bottom to be the earliest date and the minimum speed.

Comment: I was going to do that since the values are so large compared to their variation. I just haven got there yet.